# How can I change the volume of an app, even if it's not playing anything?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

The volume mixer in Ubuntu only shows apps that are playing audio. How can I change the volume of an app when it isn't?

For an example, when using Firefox, some websites will play audio. I can't prevent this beforehand, so I will either have to mute my entire system or scramble to turn Firefox down in settings.